# cocos 2d-x (3.1rc0) + Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

I have Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition.

I created a new Cocos2d-x project according to this documentation 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game

I tried to build the project with:

```
cocos run -s ~/MyCompany/MyGame -p ios
```

I get the following error

```
Runing command: compile
Building mode: debug
building
Required VS version : 11.0
Can't find correct Visual Studio's path in the regedit
```

What can I do that cocos2d-x is working with vs 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VS 2013 isn't supported until version: `cocos2d-x-3.1-alpha1`

See: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/CHANGELOG

Comment: I am using rc0 which is newer than alpha1. rc0 should support vs too.

Comment: and just to be sure, is there a Registry entry for VS 2013?

Comment: There are a lot of registry entries for vs 2013 / vs 12. Can you be more specific and give me the registry-path where it should be?